# GD image generating bug

Tags: php, gd

I'm using GD to generate images on the fly for title images on the page. There are over 100 images generated at the moment, the vast majority of which work great.

Recently we found certain titles were breaking the image creation where a large horizontal space was inserted between 2 characters.

The font being used for image generation is Interstate, and following are some examples of the titles working, along with an example of a broken one. In the case of the broken title it was the characters "JB" near each other that broke it. Flipping the characters around or having any number of characters between them results in the image being generated correctly.

As you can see from the examples the titles work with both short and long portions of text, it's just that one example that breaks it so far, really starting to confuse me and suspecting a bug in either the font file or GD, any suggestions?

[alt text http://far.id.au/jkf/so/jb.png](http://far.id.au/jkf/so/jb.png)
[alt text http://far.id.au/jkf/so/bj.png](http://far.id.au/jkf/so/bj.png)
[alt text http://far.id.au/jkf/so/cheesecake.png](http://far.id.au/jkf/so/cheesecake.png)
[alt text http://far.id.au/jkf/so/blah.png](http://far.id.au/jkf/so/blah.png)

Code:

```
private function GenerateImage()
{
    $height = 31;
    $width = $this->Width;

    $x = 10;
    $y = 20;

    $font_size = 10;

    $text_colours = $this->ToRGB($this->TextColour);
    $background_colours = $this->ToRGB($this->BackgroundColour);

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);

    $fg_color = imagecolorallocate($image,$text_colours[0],$text_colours[1],$text_colours[2]);
    $bg_color = imagecolorallocate($image,$background_colours[0],$background_colours[1],$background_colours[2]);

    imagefill($image,0,0,$bg_color);

    imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,$x,$y,$fg_color,$this->Font,strtoupper($this->Title));

    return imagepng($image,$this->FilePath,9);
}
```

Comment: Without any actual code, it's mostly guessing.

Comment: My bad, meant to upload the function, it's there now.

Comment: If you use a different font, something common like arial, does it work correctly?

Comment: 1. what happens if you use a different font size? 2. is the input string really ok? i can't remember how GD handles tabs ... (altough i don't think that's the problem)

Comment: Tried varying the font size both up and down, same result. I ended up testing this extensively, including with a hardcoded string variable that didn't have any spaces, just the string "JB".

Comment: Will try different font, it's essential that I use the one that is already there though.

Comment: Different font file fixed it, will try to repair font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrupt font was to blame